# 2D array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, search, 2d

I'm trying to set up a search for names in a code, so I'm doing a 2D array to store the names. however I'm not getting the desired output from doing this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main ()
{
    char name [4][20], string [20];
    int count; 
    for (count = 0; count <3; count ++)
    {
        printf ("Enter your name \n ");
        scanf ("%s", &string);
        strcpy (name [count], string);
    }
    for (count = 0; count <3; count ++)
    {
        printf ("%s \n \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This line `printf ("%s \n \n");`  tries to exactly print the value of which *variable*, please?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N_NAME 4
#define NAME_LENGTH 20

int main ()
{
    char names[N_NAME][NAME_LENGTH];

    // input
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i<N_NAME ; i++) {
        printf("Enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", names[i]);
    }

    // output
    for(i = 0; i<N_NAME ; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", names[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Please check this. It should be what you're looking for.

Few things to point out in your original code:

1. There's no need for "string" since you've stored what you need in the 2D char array.
2. Use "i" instead of count, which is better for writing clean code.
3. To make the %s in printf work, you have to give corresponding variable (pointer).

Comment: Yeah I literally just noticed I had to variable haha

My variables have to be 'meaningful' or Iose marks, thanks for your help!

Comment: Also `i` does not need to be signed. The preferred type to index arrays is the unsigned `size_t`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main ()
{
    char name [4][20], string [20];
    for (int row = 0; row <4; row ++)
    {
        printf ("%s \n \n");
        for (int col = 0; col <20; col ++)
        {
           printf ("Enter your name \n ");
           scanf ("%s", &string);
           strcpy (name [row][col], string);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what's the idea behind your modifications. As it stands the code does not seem to do what the OP is trying to achieve.